# How to change "from" address of email received via Email services

Tags: apex, email, apex-email-service, singleemailmessage, inboundservices

I am using Email services to catch the emails sent to Salesforce Email address configured in Email service. As we know, email address can not be set up as a custom address and has to be in a format generated by Salesforce. Ex : `my-email-address@asdlkj32987jknd23d.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com` . But the requirement that I have is that emails received has to go to a custom email address which would be configurable Ex : `support@mycompany.com`.

To achieve this, I am writing a class that implements `messaging.inboundemail` interface and forward the email received to `support@mycompany.com`. The problem here is that when `support@mycompany.com` gets the email, "from" address is the email of "context user" defined for that email service. Is there any way we can set this "from" address to that email address which has actually sent the email.

PS : Org wide defaults won't work here because email are being sent to SF from any 3rd person outside the organisation.

Comment: why don't you have your IT department autoforward emails sent to support@mycompany.com to the inbound email services address?

Comment: @cropredy : The emails will be sent to/received in email service address (as they are set in "replyTo" for previous email we send) and not to support@mycompany.com. We need to receive emails to SF configure email address because I need to run some logic in InboundEmail handler class on reception of email.

Comment: so you are saying that if `foo@me.com` sends email to `support@mycompany.com` that is then forwarded to `my-emailaddress@asdlk....salesforce.com` that the inbound email service sees the from address as the context user for the Apex Inbound email service?

Comment: no...`foo@me.com` sends an email to `my-emailaddress@asdlk....salesforce.com` and that is handled in apex inbound email service class where some processing is done on this email. A copy of this email is made and is sent to `support@mycompany.com` from this inbound handler class. Now since this email is sent from apex email service that runs in email service context user, `support@mycompany.com` sees that context user's email where it should ideally be seeing `foo@me.com`